# Optimization problem

Tags: constrained-optimization, convex-optimization

In the expression:

$${\underset{\Omega}{\min}\left\|\beta A\Omega^{-1}B+C\right\|_{F}^{2}}\, ,$$
$$\text{subject to tr}(\Omega)=1,  \Omega \ge 0\, ,$$

where ${\Omega}$ is nonnegative and symmetric matrix.

How to solve for the variable $\Omega$?

Comment: Does $\Omega \ge 0$mean that elements of $\Omega$ are nonnegative elementwise, or that $\Omega$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Are you minimizing that expression? You need to say so (edit the question).

Comment: yes, this is a minimization problem, and ${\Omega}$ is a symmetric matrix and any element of Ω is nonnegative.

Comment: There are many issues with this post, but if we can fix'em, it is an interesting question. Is $\Omega$ full or is there a fixed sparsity pattern? This looks like a sparse approximate inverse problem, and it is clear that if $\Omega$ is full then this is very expensive to solve.

Comment: Yes, in fact, ${\Omega \in R^{c \times c}}$ and ${\Omega}$ has the full rank.

Comment: Not full rank, but dense (full). Dense means that all the entries can be nonzero, while sparse matrices have a few entries compared to their size.

Comment: I have tried to solve the problem by derivation. However, I failed.

Comment: Do we know anything about A, B, C, W, or beta?

Comment: A, B, C and W are coefficient matrices, and beta is also a parameter

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\O{\Omega}\def\M{\mho}\def\t{\theta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\TE{\trace{E}}
$The constraints can be eliminated via construction.

Starting with an
unconstrained matrix $U$ define an element-wise exponential and re-scale it
$$\eqalign{
E &= \exp(U) \qiq E\ge 0 \\
\O &= \frac{E}{\TE} \qiq \trace{\O}=1,\;\O\ge 0 \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define some new variables (and redefine some existing ones)
$$\eqalign{
\t &= \TE,\qquad A = \beta A,\quad \M = \O^{-1},\quad M=A\M B+C \\
Q &= \frac{\M^TA^TMB^T\M^T}{\t^2} \\
R &= {\trace{Q^TE}\,I - \t\,Q} \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;\doteq\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
and $\odot$ for the Hadamard product, which (amazingly) commutes with the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{B\odot C} = \LR{A\odot B}:C \\
}$$
Use the above notation to calculate the differential and gradient of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \frac 12M:M \\
d\phi &= M:dM \\
  &= M:\LR{A\,d\M\,B} \\
  &= M:\LR{-A\M\;d\O\;\M B} \\
  &= -\M^TA^TMB^T\M^T:{d\O} \\
  &= -\M^TA^TMB^T\M^T:\LR{ \frac{\t\,dE-E\,\c{d\t}}{\t^2} } \\
  &= Q:\BR{E\c{\LR{I:dE}}} - Q:\t\,dE \\
  &= R:dE \\
  &= R:\LR{E\odot dU} \\
  &= \LR{R\odot E}:dU \\
\grad{\phi}{U} &= {R\odot E} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields a complicated nonlinear equation which is impossible to solve analytically. Instead, use the gradient derived above in your favorite
*gradient descent* algorithm to calculate the optimal $U$.
$\;$ Hint: The $k^{th}$ iteration will look like
$$\eqalign{
U_{k+1} &= U_k -\lambda_k{R_k\odot E_k} \\
}$$
where the step-length $\lambda_k$ is determined by a line search or some heuristic formula.

After obtaining the optimal $U$ you can then calculate the corresponding $\O$ matrix.

### Update

${\rm If}\;\O^T\!=\O\,
\big({\rm and\,therefore\;}U^T\!=U,\;E^T\!=E\big)$
the gradient should be symmetrized
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{U} &= \LR{\frac{R+R^T}{2}}\odot E \\
}$$